# Are there diferences in the physically based shader implementation in Unreal Engine 4, Unity 5, and three.js

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, unreal-engine4, pbr

Are there differences between the physically based shader implementations in Unreal Engine 4, Unity 5, and Three.js implementation?

If yes, what are they and how do they differ in terms of visual appearence?

Answer (score 3):

Since you or someone else here is asking this question again, I will try to give it an answer.

With `PBR` there is not just *this one Shader* to implement and everything looks awesome:

> PBR is more of a concept than a strict set of rules, and as such, the exact implementations of PBR systems tend to vary.

I recommend reading some articles about `PBR`, for example:

- http://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/learn/pbr-theory
- http://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/learn/pbr-practice

`Three.js` is slowly advancing in terms of Materials, Lighting, Reflections and some more techniques to create realistic looking scenes. If you are interessted how things are going you can follow or contribute to the various Issues and Pull-requests on Github regarding the new `MeshStandardMaterial`/`MeshPhysicalMaterial`:

- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5847
- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7397
- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7381

**tldr**; yes, dont try to compare a mature Game-Engine versus a webGL Library in terms of rendering Quality.

Comment: thank you. I've seen the marmoset articles before but I was not able to understand if the implementations are different between the three engines by reading it...  and why. 
My intention is not to compare a big engine to a small engine ( think three.js is great and I use it whenever I can )... my intention is just to understand the differences between the pbr in them ...thank you again